# nginx server configuration error nginx: [emerg] invalid variable name in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:156

Tags: nginx

I have issue with nginx configuration, when i try to run it its giving me error :

1. nginx: [emerg] invalid variable name in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:156
   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
   nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1  Failed
   to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.  Unit
   nginx.service entered failed state  nginx.service failed.

Below this is my configuration file.

Please notice it is REACTJS website.

Thanks infront

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream some_upsteram_com {
    server 127.0.0.1:7000;
    keepalive 15;
}

server {
 listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  socket.domain.com;
location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/folder/socket;
             index index.html index.htm;
}
ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/socketserver.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/socketserver.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_error_socket.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/project_access_socket.log;


    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;


    location / {
        try_files $uri @nodejs;
    }


# Important! Serve client socket.io file as normal static file, e.g. /js/libs/socket.io/socket.io.min.js
    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://some_upsteram_com;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    }


    location @nodejs {
        proxy_pass http://some_upsteram_com;
    }

}









server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  api.domain.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/folder/public;

ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/apiserver.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/apiserver.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
       try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
   }
   location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

         fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
       return 404;
   }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error_api.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access_api.log;
    }


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    return       301 https://domain.c0m$request_uri;
}
 server {
    listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  www.domain.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/folder/public;

    rewrite ^/faq/$ /en/faq permanent;
    rewrite ^/quote/$ /en/contact-us permanent;
    rewrite ^/reviews/$ / permanent;

    location / {
       try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
   }
   location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

         fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
       return 404;
   }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
    }



# Settings for a TLS enabled server.

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  www.domain.com;
    root  /usr/share/nginx/folder/public;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/server.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/server.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

 # Enable Gzip
  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers     4 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types
    # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
    text/css
    text/javascript
    text/xml
    text/plain
    text/x-component
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    font/truetype
    font/opentype
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    image/svg+xml;

  gzip_static on;

  gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_vary           on;



# Cache
location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    tcp_nodelay off;

    open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
    open_file_cache_valid 45s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
}


    rewrite ^/faq/$ /en/faq permanent;
    rewrite ^/quote/$ /en/contact-us permanent;
    rewrite ^/reviews/$ / permanent;



location / {
       try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
   }
   location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
   }

location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       return 404;
   }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;

    }

}
```

Comment: The error points to line number 156. However there is nothing wrong with that line that I can see. The fact that the first `server` block has two `location /` blocks is the error that I get.

Comment: Yes i have removed that , but got same error again and -t gives syntax is ok.